# How to use table bucketing with ephemeral EMR clusters?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, emr, apache-spark-2.2

I'm using Spark 2.2 with ephemeral clusters on EMR.
I'd like to use spark bucketing and I don't care about Hive (Spark only workloads).

Can I use `spark.sql.warehouse.dir` with a s3 bucket to save metastore information in order to make them not cluster dependant ?

Do I also need a location for storing `metastore_db` ?

What happens behind the scene ? Where are stored information displayed by this command : `spark.catalog.listTables.show` ?